# Fix many folder permissions

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm trying to organise the permissions for a large number of folders, that each have a standard, unique read-only/modify group applied to them.

Trouble is, many of these folders each have nested groups and individual users assigned to them - it's a complete mess. I'd like to build a script that is able to take a folder, look at the the security and take all of the accounts (even from nested groups) and add them to the standard read-only or modify group we have in place.

Is this something that any of you have had to do before with powershell? If so, any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Share with us your code.  What did you try till now?

Comment: I'm not quite at that point yet! :D

Comment: @mefflecakes Then get to that point before asking a question. You should begin to ask when you are stuck, not the first thing you do when you attempt something. And if your permission structure is "a complete mess", then you are likely setting yourself up for complete failure down the road.

Comment: appreciate that, obviously misunderstood how this place works. fyi i didn't make the structure this way, i'm merely trying to get it sorted (with very little ps knowledge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this page: 
[File System Security PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85)

You need to pipe a file or directory to `Get-NTFSAccess` and by adding a Account Parameter you ll only get the Accounts back. 
So it should look something like that:

```
Get-Item "C:\UrPath" | Get-NTFSAccess -Account
```

So now u got all accounts for a file or directory.

Granting access to a file or folder is also quite easy to do by using the `Add-NTFSAccess` cmdlet.

Removing access is similar to adding permissions. The command `Remove-NTFSAccess` takes the same parameters as `Add-NTFSAccess`.

So have a look at the module provided via url above.